# Fixing "Couldn't find device with uuid" error in RHEL

Tags: linux, lvm, rhel-6, lvm2

How can I restore the missing volume? I get the below error message and I am trying to fix it. It would be great, if someone could guide me here. Shared all the outputs below for better understanding of the issue.

```
# lvs
  Couldn't find device with uuid ntc7O9-wevl-ZtXz-xESe-wwUB-G8WZ-6RtjxB.
  Couldn't find device with uuid 56ogEk-OzLS-cKBc-z9vJ-kP65-DUBI-hwZPSu.
  Couldn't find device for segment belonging to vg_jd/lv_tpa while checking used and assumed devices.
```

Comment: What is output of `lvs -ao+devices` and `pvs`?

Comment: The most likely answer is going to be: it depends... If the missing pvs are back, `vgextend --restoremissing vg_jd` should do the trick. If these were faulty drives, but you managed to rescue some data from them (e.g. using dd_rescue), the same applies. If they are not back, the LV is partial, and it may be difficult to restore anything for that. You could try some forensic tools. After salvaging any data, you can remove the LV using `vgreduce --removemissing vg_jd` so you can use the VG without constraints.